# Why is neutral to ground not 120V?

Tags: transformer, split-phase

I'm so stuck.  If we look at a center tapped transformer for US service, L1 to L2 is 240V.  L1 to N is 120V because effectively you're only using half the length of the coil.  Makes sense.  But why is N to ground (earth) not 120V?  In the same way that we have phase shifting L1 vs L2 = 240V, why not phase shifting between N and ground = 120V?  It just doesn't make sense.  Btw I understand N and ground are tied together at the breaker panel.

Comment: Usually neutral is physically connected to ground, so they have to be at the same voltage.  If you connected L1 or L2 to ground, then yes it would be at 120V relative to ground.

Comment: `Btw I understand N and ground are tied together at the breaker panel.` ... and you still expect to measure more than a couple of volts between them?

Comment: Reposting my same comment from below, my point is, in the same way that if you measure L1 to G and L2 to G you get a voltage (potential), why not if you measure N to G? Essentially N is just another "L" tied to the center of the transformer... an "L3" if you will.

Comment: So do you really understand what the N and ground being tied together at the panel means?

Comment: ^^ So hypothetically if I were to tie L1 to straight to ground then it would become a neutral?  That's essentially what we're doing with "L3" (center tapped) running it straight into the ground.  To me that seems like we're just running 120V open ended straight into the earth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a voltage is a relative thing. You cannot describe the voltage of the output of a single transformer wire, because what voltage it possesses is only relative to some other part of the same circuit - in this case, the only other part is the other end of the transformer. Because the transformer is galvanically isolated, there is only a potential between one wire and the other. This is why birds can perch on a live, uninsulated wire harmlessly.

Now let's modify that transformer secondary to add a center tap. You can consider the transformer now being two separate transformer secondaries, with one end of each tied to the other.

So let's look at one half of the secondary. Between the center tap and the other end, there's (say) 120V.

Between the center tap and the opposite end of the *other* winding, there's also 120V.

Between the outside pairs, there's 240V. How is this additive when the center tap is the same potential in both cases?

Look closely at the winding of the transformer. Both ends are wound in the same direction, so the whole transformer winds up being 240V. If you look at half of the winding and the center tap, you get 120V, but if you look at it on an oscilloscope, you'll see that relative to the center tap, the output at each end of the transformer is 180º out of phase. Why?

Because for one half to the transformer, the center tap is the *top* of the winding, and for the other half, the center tap is the *bottom* of the winding.

The only point left to explain is that the center tap is connected to earth. This is entirely for safety, as in almost every ordinary circumstance, you - the human reading this - is at or near ground potential (unless you're actively rubbing your rubber soled shoes on a carpet in dry air). It would be unsafe for you to interact with anything that wasn't also at ground potential (that is, at ground voltage - 0V). So we tend to want to make sure that we connect as many things that are within finger range of a human to ground as we can. If a wiring fault develops and allows a significant voltage source to connect to the chassis of a thing, then a high current will result, which should cause the breaker in the distribution panel to open (with the hope being that this path to ground is preferred over a path through the user's body).

Comment: thanks for this answer.  This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> Btw I understand N and ground are tied together at the breaker panel.

That's the key!  When you tie two points together with a conductor, you cause then to be at the SAME potential.  So N and G should be the same voltage, in theory at least.  In practice there will be a slight difference depending on where you measure and how much current is flowing through N.

So if you measure H1 to H2, you will get 240V.
If you measure H1 to N or H2 to N you will get 120V.
If you measure N to G you will get 0V (or something close to 0V).

Comment: Thanks!  So wouldnt that mean you're sending 120V straight into the ground?  I mean I realize voltage is relative, but that earth to "some other reference" would be 120V?

Comment: @nms553 Fig. 1 on this wiki article might make it more clear what is happened:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power  But no, since the neutral is at 0v, you are not connecting 120v to ground.

Comment: But my point is, in the same way that if you measure L1 to G and L2 to G you get a voltage (potential), why not if you measure N to G?  Essentially N is just another "L" tied to the center of the transformer... an "L3" if you will.

Comment: @nms553 N and G are connected, so you will always measure zero, or very close to it (due to wire resistances, etc).

Comment: so hypothetically if you disconnect G from N at the breaker panel, you would measure 120V N to G (earth) from the circuit?

Comment: @nms553 To get 120V N to G you would have to ground either L1 or L2.  If you disconnect everything from ground then you are floating with respect to ground and (ignoring leakage currents) cannot measure anything to ground since you lack a complete electrical circuit to measure.

Comment: @mms553: If you disconnect N from ground, then everything on the secondary side, including N, L1 and L2 is completely isolated from everything else. Those voltages are then ***undefined*** with respect to ground. Any voltage you measure between ground and N (or L1 or L2) will be signals coupled into those nodes from whatever other sources are present in the environment; effectively just noise.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5WlNH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Perhaps a wiring diagram will help. L1 and L2, in conjunction with Neutral, are the two 120V phases that feed the ordinary wall outlets. Note that L2 is 180° out of phase with L1 which is why the voltage between L1 & L2 is 240V.

For high power devices like stoves, water heaters, dryers, HVAC, ... 240V is provided which use the L1 and L2 legs. Neutral is, or is not, part of the 240V system (depends on wiring and outlets), however, Earth is always provided for safety.

The Earth connections normally don't carry significant current and is there just for safety purposes.

Note: For simplicity sake, the above drawing doesn't show circuit breakers which is normally part of the distribution panel.

You can see from the diagram that the voltage between Neutral and Earth will be zero Volts for a system without faults since Neutral and Earth are tied together in the distribution panel.

Answer (score 1):

GROUND is simply where you define 0 V as a reference.  In a floating circuit you can call anything 0V.

Some cars once had positive ground and -V batteries for some galvanic reason.

It can be floating but not 240V, otherwise Neutral becomes 240V to the home.

Earth GROUND is 0 V and earth bonded too.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is neutral to ground not 120V?

That's because its the neutral, not L1 or L2, that  is connected to ground.

[image]

Comment: In theory, what would happen if we moved the ground connection from the center-tap to L1 instead?  Would the N now become 120V for example?

Comment: Yes, @nms553, it would.

Answer (score 0):

> But why is N to ground (earth) not 120V?

**Neutral** is called neutral because it **has been** **neutralised** **by connecting it to ground**. It no longer poses a threat<sup>1</sup>. In normal operation the voltage on the neutral wire will be between 0 V and a few volts depending on the current flowing in the neutral wire.

Since it has been neutralised a neutral to earth (ground) fault will not cause a high fault current so the neutral lines are generally not fused.

> In the same way that we have phase shifting L1 vs L2 = 240V, ...

Actually there is no phase shift. They are the same phase but since they are centre-grounded they appear as two lines 180° out of phase.

> ... why not phase shifting between N and ground = 120V?

See above. Neutral has a direct connection to ground. There should be no potential difference.

> It just doesn't make sense.

It should by now.

> Btw I understand N and ground are tied together at the breaker panel.

So then it should be clear that there can't be a potential difference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpZV2j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple DC example using 9 V DC batteries. (a) Negative ground. (b) Centre ground. (c) Positive ground.*

In your question you are describing a situation analogous to (b) above. It should be clear that since the centre-tap has been grounded that VM3 must read 0 V.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are various fault conditions such as a broken neutral wire between the load and the supply transformer that can cause the neutral wire between the load and the break to become live.

Comment: Thanks, so if N not connected to G we would get something like this?  [https://nms553.github.com/circuit.png](https://nms553.github.io/circuit.png)

Comment: I don't know what that diagram is supposed to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

The generator is like an electrical motor with coils moving past a magnet. So your L1 and L2 are connected to coils with induction. Neutral and Ground are just grounded in different places, sometimes they're a few volts apart but in the US they're typically connected in the breaker box (or sometimes through plumbing in older homes).

Really the city transformers you see in the street (often on poles) have three phases.